# Multithread runtime profiling for C++

Tags: c++, multithreading, profiling

I have a multi-thread program written in C++ runs on CentOS. To check the runtime improvement, I print out the `user time`, `sys time`, and `real time`. I used `std::mutex` in my implementation.

I would like to clarify that, the cost of putting threads to sleep and waking them up again would be count into `sys time` or `user time`?

Then what about the time that threads are sleeping?

I can see the runtime improvement after using multithreading. However the `sys time` increases.

Comment: Everything that a program does which involves a system call must necessary involve both user and system time. When the application constructs a `std::thread`, or locks a `std::mutex`, this doesn't happen instantly. To do so will require breaking several fundamental laws of physics of our shared universe. Extremely unlikely. Some overhead is required to pull together all the parameters and make the system call. From that point on it's considered system time until the return to userspace.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik So to be more precisely, can we say "If the mutex is currently locked by another thread, execution of the calling thread is blocked. The duration of this blockage would mostly contribute to the sys time"?

Comment: No, I do not believe that to be the case. A process that's sleeping on a mutex is not going to rack up any time, system or user.